# .val is not giving me the value of my element

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, reddit

I am working with a reddit API. I have a search box on my page and I am trying to set it up so that if one were to type virtually anything it would return the top 10 news stories related to the word or phrase they typed.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

       //reddit API URL
       //var URL =  "http://www.reddit.com/r/subreddits/search.json?q=Xbox";

       var SEARCH_URL = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/subreddits/search.json?jsonp=?';
       var searchQueryText = $('#search').val(); //getSearchQueryText();

       $.getJSON(SEARCH_URL, {
          q: searchQueryText,
          limit: 10
       }).done(function (data) {
           $.each(data.data.children, function (i, item) {
             $("<p>").text(item.data.title).appendTo("#images");
           });
       }).fail(function (data) {
           alert("Something went wrong");
       });

    }); //end ready
 </script>
```

```
<div id="images">
<h1>Reddit Data:</h1>

<p>
    <label>Search</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "search" value = "" />
</p>
```

If I change the var `SearchQueryText` to a specific word than the API works fine. However since I changed it to the `$('#search').val();` it no longer works. I put an `alert()` to test for the value and the pop-up is blank. So I think the problem is it doesn't detect the word when I type it. So I wrote a simple `.mouseenter` function and still nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: You're taking the value of the text box before you type anything.

Comment: I suspected that. So do I need to write a function to have the var searchQueryText take it after I write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try attaching a `keyup` event handler

This will fire when ever the user releases the key.

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    console.log(this.value)
}).change();
```

If you want to fire the same on document ready then you can just chain the event after the declaration.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#search').keyup(function () {
        //reddit API URL
        //var URL =  "http://www.reddit.com/r/subreddits/search.json?q=Xbox";

        var SEARCH_URL = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/subreddits/search.json?jsonp=?';
        var searchQueryText = this.value;  // or  $(this).val(()

        $.getJSON(SEARCH_URL, {
            q: searchQueryText,
            limit: 10
        }).done(function (data) {
            $.each(data.data.children, function (i, item) {
                $("<p>").text(item.data.title).appendTo("#images");

            });
        }).fail(function (data) {
            alert("Something went wrong");
        });
    }).keyup();
}); //end ready
```

Comment: You mean set var searchQueryText = $('#search').change(function() {
    console.log(this.value)
}); right?

Comment: I'm sorry I am a bit of a rookie. Do you mean literally put everything in because that doesn't make sense to me?

Comment: Basically you want to send a request every time the user types something in the search bar. The code that you have written will only execute once when the page loads.  But encasing this inside the event handler will make sure the request is sent and new data fetched whenever the text changes

Comment: It retrieved the information but It also caused problems. For instance It didn't stop at my limit of 10 that I set. I tried to do a click method but I couldn't get it to work. I'm told that's the easier way so I'm going to try that again.

Comment: Instead just encase the same but inside a click event. Try creating a button element and assign the event to it

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could fire the event whenever the user presses the enter key (i.e. after inputting some text) like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#search').keypress(function(e) {
     if(e.which == 13) {
       // Enter key pressed
       e.preventDefault();
       var SEARCH_URL = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/subreddits/search.json?jsonp=?';
       var searchQueryText = $('#search').val(); //getSearchQueryText();
       console.log(searchQueryText);

       $.getJSON(SEARCH_URL, {
          q: searchQueryText,
          limit: 10
       }).done(function (data) {
          $.each(data.data.children, function (i, item) {
          $("<p>").text(item.data.title).appendTo("#images");
          });
       }).fail(function (data) {
         alert("Something went wrong");
       });   
     }
  }); // End keypress handler
}); // End ready
```